# Add Image Geolocation

Tags: digital, metadata, windows

Is there a program that can batch process exif data? I'd like to add geolocations to my images and I have about 2000 pictures?

Answer (score 5):

Lightroom is how I do this. It's fairly easy to drop a picture, or set of pictures, to a location on the map or to synchronize it with a GPS log from your phone or, in my case, watch.

Answer (score 2):

exiftool (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is a command line utility that will do this. Its free, runs on all platforms, etc.

If you are comfortable using the command line, its a lot faster to do thousands of files than any GUI can be.